# Editable Combobox in WPF GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a GridView that is bound to data using MVVM.

I want the users to be able to select an available description from a list or write a text.

I also want the Description list to change based on the values in SL column.

Here is my code:

```
  <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" Width="180">
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description1}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <telerik:RadComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SLStandardDescriptions}" 
                                   Text="{Binding Description1,Mode=TwoWay}">
                  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                      <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened">
                          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SLStandardDescriptionsDropDownOpenedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                      </i:EventTrigger>
                  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
              </telerik:RadComboBox>
          </DataTemplate>
      </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
  </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

and in ViewModel:

```
private async void OnSLStandardDescriptionsDropDownOpened()
{
    if (AccDocumentItem?.SL != null)
    {
        AccDocumentItem.SLStandardDescriptions = await _uow.SLStandardDescriptions.Where(x => x.SLId == AccDocumentItem.SLId).Select(x=>x.SLStandardDescriptionTitle).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" Width="180">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadComboBox IsEditable="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding SLStandardDescriptions}" 
                Text="{Binding Description1,Mode=TwoWay}"     >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SLStandardDescriptionsDropDownOpenedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>

</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I don't want ComboBox in  CellTemplate, I want to show ComboBox only in CellEditTemplate.